# Test Bootstrap modals with Codeception and PhantomJs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, phantomjs, bootstrap-modal, codeception

I'm getting started with Codeception and PhantomJS for acceptance tests.

Here's my `acceptance.suite.yml`

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: http://localhost/
            browser: firefox
            window_size: 1280x1024
            wait: 2s
        - \Helper\Acceptance
```

And my acceptance test

```
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('Check that something');
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->click('element that opens a bootstrap modal');
$I->see("Something on the modal");
```

I've a PhantomJS server started with `./phantomjs --webdriver=4444` and I launch my tests with `php codecept.phar run acceptance`.

However, the test fails with

```
 Step  I see "Something on the modal"
 Fail  Failed asserting that   /
[...]
--> contains "Something on the modal".
```

while the screenshot in the `_output` directory shows the modal and `"Something on the modal"`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its because acceptance.yml says browser 'firefox' and it should be  'phantomjs'.